# TextFormField multiple input lines

Tags: flutter, dart

I am doing a contact form and in the body I need it to be higher and be able to put enter (as if you press enter it stops writing.

This is my current code:

```
TextFormField(
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter a ${widget.name}';
        }
        return null;
      },
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white
      ),
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: kBlue)),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
        labelText: 'Enter the ${widget.name}',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  minLines: 2,
  maxLines: 3,
)
```